# How to release "idle" brake of a three-phase motor?

Tags: motor, three-phase, vfd

I am using a three-phase motor (Segmotor SS Serie) with a VFD ([Delta VFD-EL-W](https://www.deltaww.com/en-us/products/AC-Motor-Drives/5695)).
When not under tension, the motor's shaft is blocked by a brake.
How can I bypass this brake?
(either directly on the motor or on the VFD to enable freewheel when Frequency=0)

This particular model (EL W) specifies that is not equipped with a "brake resistor" or brake unit. But the wiring provides output with parameters related to braking:

[image]

<sub>Image source: [Delta VFD-EL-W Series Simplified Manual](https://filecenter.deltaww.com/Products/download/06/060101/Manual/DELTA_IA-MDS_VFD-EL-W_SM_SC-EN_20230221.pdf)</sub>

The output parameters:

[image]

<sub>Image adapted from: [Delta VFD-EL-W Series Simplified Manual](https://filecenter.deltaww.com/Products/download/06/060101/Manual/DELTA_IA-MDS_VFD-EL-W_SM_SC-EN_20230221.pdf)</sub>

Extra question: If one of these parameters enable me to freely release the brake even without tension, do you think these outputs can be controlled via the RS-485 I will use to remote control the VFD?

Thank for your help =) I'm an artist and it's my first project with three-phase electricity.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [edit] your post to show a diagram of the wiring between the VFD and motor? From a brief skim of some manuals, it looks like the VFD has a relay output that might be used for controlling a brake (RA/RB/RC) and the manual mentions how it may be configured, but we wouldn't know for sure without checking against the way your motor is currently wired.

Comment: Thank you, I did that!

Comment: @JoKolski - Hi (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules here differ from typical forums. (b) I removed the advertising / non-essential links. Unlike typical forums, a link here needs to be *directly* relevant to the question. I expect the advertising was an innocent mistake and not the real reason for the question i.e. I don't think you're a spammer. (c) Finally, anything copied from elsewhere needs a proper reference, so I added what I think is the correct link (x2). If you copied that info from a different Delta document, please update the link. Thanks.

Comment: (FYI, you can add links to your work and future performances etc. by editing [your profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/edit/349059) "About Me" section.)

Comment: @JoKolski: what type of brake are you using, is it magnetic? If yes, the brake voltage should be in the motor plate.

Comment: By any chance, are you able to check parameter `08.00` for the VFD? Its default should be set to 0, but it seems to provide some kind of braking functionality that doesn't involve  an external brake. Also, confirming what's wired into RA/RB/RC in your specific setup, in conjunction with knowing the value for parameter `03.00`, would help confirm whether an external braking mechanism might be wired in

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when not under tension"? Are you referring to mechanical tension, or are you using "under tension" to mean "with voltage applied"? ("tension" is the English cognate of the word used for voltage in many other languages, but in modern English the word only refers to the mechanical concept. It's a common mistake for non-native English speakers.)